# Skyrim PS4 edition cheat codes

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps4, cheats

Are there any cheat codes (certain combinations of buttons, etc.) on the PS4 edition of Skyrim? I was hoping there might be a code that gives me a jump boost or reduced fall damage, as I'm currently stuck on the side of a mountain with no way up or down.

Comment: Should have brought a horse.

Comment: A couple of options:Fast travel to get out of there.  If you cannot then just reload from a previous save.  If you have the whirlwind sprint you can use that to move to another place.

Comment: @Iszi Lol, I don't have a horse. I've just started a new play-through of the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no cheat codes. On Windows, you can use the console, but that isn't possible for the PS4.

As [fja3omega](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/136802/fja3omega) mentioned in a comment, your best bet is probably to use fast travel to move somewhere else. You could also try to run/jump sideways along the rocks and get to somewhere more convenient.

If you happen to know the [Become Ethereal shout](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Become_Ethereal), just use that and then jump off the cliff. You'll survive the fall no matter how far it is.

Comment: Well, where I was at on the side of the mountain, I wasn't able to fast travel. It said that I was falling/jumping. And I don't have that Shout... I actually don't have any Shouts yet. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh, I haven't experienced that. Maybe you were slipping on the rocks or something, so the game thought you were falling. I hope you figured something out, anyway.

Comment: I did. I decided to die lol.

Comment: Haha, well that's one way out of that situation. :p

Comment: Lol yeah. I am actually level 100 in all my skills already, but I don't have Shouts yet. I chose to use the method where you run around the entire map and discover all the locations you can before you do the Bleak Falls Barrow quests. This way, I won't encounter any dragons and will be able to fast travel anywhere I need to go, rather than having to walk and then ending up having to fight dragons on the way. So, dragons aren't appearing in my game, so I can't get souls to activate the few Shouts I've learned.

Answer (score -3):

There are mods for PS4. Just press "mods" if you are logged in and then you will find them.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I know there are mods. However, at the time I posted this question, I still had not fully beat the game, and had no interest in modding my experience.